# How to make a role only accessible via AzureConnect

Tags: azure

Is it possible to configure a role endpoint that **only** allows communication over Azure Connect? ie, I have a web application that I do not want to expose to the outside world, but would like local endpoints (Azure Connect machines) to have access to without additional security.

In a full-vpn scenario this would just happen, but I'm struggling to define/setup in the constraints of Azure Connect and the csdef.  I have role(s) communicating with on-campus resources via connect, but I can't seem to limit access to these resources without declaring a standard http Endpoint.  Tried just creating an internal Endpoint, but it appears this is only allowing access w/i the actual datacenter (b/t hosted roles)

Answer (score 0):

I think that an internal endpoint would do the trick. That would get IIS (assuming you're using a web role) to listen on the right (be sure to specify one so you know what it is), and it won't open up to traffic from the internet.

What happens when you use an internal endpoint and try to connect to it?  And do other sorts of connections work?  (Are you sure Connect itself is working?)

Comment: Assuming Azure Connect is working as I can RDP to the role and navigate shares on my local machine from there.  But with that + only an internal Endpoint in the .csdef, I can't find any way to to get to the web code.  I'm gonna toy with IIS on the box in the morning and try to reverse engineer my own misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, now Im officially confused.  I can ping Azure->local.  I can ping (after opening up the rule) local->azure.  I can HTTP Azure->Local and use web apps on my machine from role.  I cannot, however, find any way to address the role from my machine(local) and hit IIS.  I've tried every IP address I can think of.  Tried using the IIS log IP from Azure->Local, but that appears to be a puesdo-ip of the Azure Connect connector.  What DNS should I be using?  If this is working and I have a role labeled "RD0001", how should I be able to access the web code running on it? Any thought?

Comment: Open inetmgr on the VM and check out the binding.  I believe it will be to a 10.* IP address.  Use that.